# Spring Security Not Allowing Static Content

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-boot

I have been fighting with Spring Security for the past few days so I hope someone can help me out here.

- I am using Spring Boot 1.2.5
- I was using Spring Actuator and Spring Remote Shell, those have since been removed from the classpath thinking they may be causing issues
- I excluded SecurityAutoConfiguration on the off chance it was causing my issues

Here is my main class

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SecurityAutoConfiguration.class})
public class MyApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Here is my security configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private AuthFailureHandler authFailureHandler;

    @Autowired
    private AuthSuccessHandler authSuccessHandler;

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web
                .ignoring()
                    .antMatchers("/css/**")
                    .antMatchers("/js/**")
                    .antMatchers("/images/**");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(new Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint())
                    .accessDeniedPage("/403")
                    .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/about").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
                    .and()
                .formLogin()
                    .usernameParameter("sec-user")
                    .passwordParameter("sec-password")
                    .loginPage("/login")
                    .failureHandler(authFailureHandler)
                    .successHandler(authSuccessHandler)
                    .permitAll()
                    .and()
                .logout()
                    .deleteCookies("JESSIONID")
                    .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                    .permitAll();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    protected AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManager();
    }
}
```

My questions / issues are

1. CSS, JavaScript, Images, basically no static content will load, and I can't seem to figure out why
2. What makes things even more interesting, instead of getting a 403 error which is what I would expect, it redirects to the Login page? I don't want that, it should return 403 is they don't have access.

I am calling my static resources from Thymeleaf like so

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" th:href="@{/css/main.css}" />
```

My static resources were working fine before adding security.

My static files are in resources/public/.

This is fine acording to Spring Boot docs

> By default Spring Boot will serve static content from a folder called /static (or /public or /resources or /META-INF/resources) in the classpath or from the root of the ServletContext.

Comment: Why do you have your css/js/images mapped as urls under authorizeRequestes? you shouldn't be listing them there you should be adding them to your resource handlers and have spring do the work.

Comment: I am using Spring Boot, my understanding is it does that already through its autoconfig because it was all working fine before I added security unless I am not understanding you. They are in /resources/public which spring boot automatically maps

Comment: ".authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/css/**", "/js/**", "/images/**").permitAll()" is redundant code shouldn't be listed there. You are basically telling the system to expect <domain>/css to be a valid url to access. You can still use resource handlers with Boot. But get rid of that line and give it a whirl

Comment: I updated my config but it still isn't working. When /css/main.css is requested it returns HTML being the login page

Comment: how exactly are you trying to load the resources? can you show the view code

Comment: Okay I revamped the question so hopefully it makes more sense and provides more insight into the issue

Comment: I'm going to make assumption that page loads BUT the resource doesn't and in the console it would show you 403 error for it? or does the whole page return 403? Since you using thymeleaf try th:href="@{/resources/public/css/main.css}" sometimes you need to really point at your file to get it to realise you need it.

Comment: Okay I am starting to think this is some weird Intellij bug or data corruption because I took basically the same setup on my home desktop and it works

Comment: Ahh that could explain it. I hope you didn't do what i did and upgrade to win10. I was forced to reinstall IDEA and get project from repo.

Comment: I usually develop on a Mac, it actually ended up working on my Windows desktop, doh!. Thanks for working through this with me

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a resource handler.

```
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {

    registry.addResourceHandler("/css/**")
            .addResourceLocations("classpath:/css/**");
    registry.addResourceHandler("/img/**")
            .addResourceLocations("classpath:/img/**");
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
            .addResourceLocations("/resources/");
}
```